# How to handle the root of a Singly-Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

Let's say I have a node in a Linked List defined as follows:

```
struct movie {
    char title[50];
    int year;
};

// so we can swap in other types by changing the `typedef Item`
typedef struct movie Item;

struct node {
    Item        item;
    struct node *next;
};
```

How is the head/root of the list usually handled? Is this as simple as just doing:

```
struct node *head;
```

Or is the `LinkedList` usually handled as a wrapper struct, something like:

```
struct LinkedList_ {
    struct node* head;
    size_t size;
    // anything else?
} LinkedList;
```

And we just use the `LinkedList` and add functions around that item? For example: `LinkedList->addNode(...)`.

Comment: Both ways work, it really depends if you care about the length or not, or if you'll be cutting the list up into pieces frequently enough that having a special "head" structure would be annoying.

Comment: @tadman I see -- which way would you say is more common in practice?

Comment: Really hard to say, as "common" is a subjective thing. If you look at the Linux kernel, as one example, both approaches are used, and the choice made depends *entirely* on the situation. If you need to know the size frequently, you keep it as a counter to reduce cost. It's all about not doing work that doesn't matter.

Comment: I suggest reading about linked list in Linux kernel. See https://medium.com/@414apache/kernel-data-structures-linkedlist-b13e4f8de4bf

Comment: I prefer the separate list struct. To me, it's clearer at not much extra speed penalty. I'd add a `tail` to it. Then, the actual list can be a _doubly_ linked list if you want. Also, with `tail`, appending to end is just using `tail` vs a `for` loop. The `size` is useful if you're trying to do a mergesort on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no right and wrong here. This is more of a design decision, than anything else. For me personaly, I usually don't use any kind of wrapper, nor do I store the size, since the end of the list is marked by a null pointer. So to iterate it I usually use something like this:

```
for(struct node *current = first; current != NULL; current = current->next);
```

I also store both the head and the tail. So You can easily add nodes to the list.

```
struct node *newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode->next = NULL;
tail->next = newNode;
tail = newNode;
```